# Interpretation of impdp/expdp character set warnings

Tags: oracle, character-set, impdp

impdp and expdp report encoding warnings in the form of:

```
export done in A character set and B character set
import done in C set and C character set
```

Why do both warnings name *two* character sets? What to they refer to? It seems to be always two, so it's not just a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases have 2 character sets: 1 default character set (used by CHAR, VARCHAR2, CLOB) and 1 national character set (used by NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, NCLOB).

For example: AL32UTF8 + AL16UTF16

You can query them from `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`.

Comment: So they refer to default and national each? Thanks!